# Search in a Array 2D [AS3]

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

The content of the array respuesta is: Africa, Europa, Norteamerica. The content of the array resultado is: Incorrect, Correct, Incorrect

I created a `Array` to include both of them:

```
var contPre:Array = [ this.respuesta, this.resultado ];
```

and then:

```
for ( var row:int = 0; row & lt; contPre.length; row++ )    
{
     for ( var column:int = 0; column & lt; contPre[row].length ; column++ )
     {
            // If I want to find the value:Africa Incorrect
            // without entering this code:  contPre[0][1]  

     }

}
```

Something is wrong or I don't know why this is happening.. I made the change:

```
for (var a:uint = 0; a & lt; contPre[0].length; a++)
{

    if (this.radioGroup1.selection.value == contPre[0][a] && contPre[1][a] == "Correcto") 
    {
        result_txt.text = "Correct";
        valor = 1;

    }
    else    
    {
        result_txt.text = "Incorrect";
        valor = 0;

    }

}
```

If I choose `Europa` (`[0][1]`)... the code above go out for the Incorrect option and this result is not correct because in the `Array` is "Correct".

Answer (score 0):

```
[0][0] is Africa
[0][1] is Europe
[0][2] is NorteAmerica
[1][0] is Incorrect
[1][1] is Correct
[1][2] is Incorrect
```

In your case I'd set up a boolean FoundAfrica or w/e and set it to false.  if an element is Africa check the same column in the next row and see if it's incorrect

If it is set your boolean to true.

Answer (score 0):

You actually only need to iterate over the Array once to retrieve all values:

```
for ( var continent:int = 0; continent < contPre[0].length; continent++ ) {
     trace(contPre[0][continent] + " = " + contPre[1][continent]);  //Outputs: Continent = Answer
}
```